# Mac Terminal error

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

[image]

The first thing it does when I try to log in is display this error. On every window. can someone please help and find what 'login' is on line 400 or just know what the answer is?

I cannot access terminal to debug myself :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Disk Utility (in /Applications/Utilities), select your root volume, and in the First Aid tab click on Repair Disk Permissions.